# adding a line at the end of a bash file

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, ubuntu-11.04, ubuntu-11.10

```
-bash: /root/.bashrc: line 100: conditional binary operator expected
-bash: /root/.bashrc: line 100: syntax error near `"$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"'
-bash: /root/.bashrc: line 100: `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" #Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*'
```

I have got those output after I added

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*`
```

at the end of the `~/.bashrc`

does anyone know how to fix this ?

I would like to load rvm into the shell session

Comment: I have the feeling the error is not in this line. Try adding a hash to its front and see the output.

Comment: Please explain me how as I am a Linux novice

Comment: Add a hash('#') to the front of this line. Just a symbol.

Comment: Thanks, I see now. But isn't it just a comment-out-hash

Comment: My idea was to see if the error is on this line. Anyway now you have your answer from choroba.

Answer (score 4):

A space is missing before `]]` (guessing from the error message, not shown in you code, though).